# Looping on a protractor test

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a code some thing like this

```
describe("Main test", function(){
    var temp = [];
   it("actual test1", function(){
    ...
   });
   describe("sub main test1", function(){
      it("test", function(){
         temp.push(1);
      });
   });
   describe("sub main test2", function(){
      for(var i=0;i<temp;i++){
          it("test" + temp, function(){
             ...
          });
      }
   });
});
```

When the test starts, the `for` loop is executing, at that time the `temp` is empty. In this case the `it` block inside the `for` loop is not executing. How to execute for loop after the `sub main test1` describe block. In this way `temp` has some data.

Answer (score 0):

You should do initialization stuff in the `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` blocks (see [reference](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown)).

Therefore, the following code should do the trick.

```
describe('Main test', function () {
  var temp;
  beforeEach(function () {
    temp = [];
    temp.push(1);
  });
 ...
});
```

**Note:**

Based on your comment, what you are trying to achieve is a bit wrong, as the `it` blocks should not perform any initialization for further `it` blocks.
Every `it` block should be able to run individually.

Comment: Thanks for you response. This should work, but the "it" block in the 'sub main test1' "describe" block will do specific operations like getting text and push it 'temp' variable, like wise there are so many "describe" blocks contains "it" blocks do  the specific operations and pushing to temp. Actually if i assign a value to temp variable before executing the "it" block it is working. But what i am expecting is to 'sub main test2' describe block should execute after the 'sub main test1'. In that case temp variable has some data. is there any thing like that or any idea to do in a different way.